# Normal distribution probability density function for dummies

Tags: normal-distribution

Could someone explain in plain English the parts of Gaussian PDF? Why $\pi$, why Euler constant etc.

$$f(x; \mu, \sigma^2) = \dfrac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left\{-\frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{x - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right\}.$$

Comment: Uhh, I think a textbook might be better for this.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/28564/152225).

Comment: @AntoniParellada thx

Comment: That [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/what-do-pi-and-e-stand-for-in-the-normal-distribution-formula/28564#28564) says everything except why the $x^2$ appears in the exponent.  For that, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest [cumulant-generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulant#Alternative_definition_of_the_cumulant_generating_function) of a non-constant variable is quadratic, say $i\mu t-\frac12\sigma^2t^2$ (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem) for further motivation). It can be shown the resulting distribution has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, and the PDF you cited. Because of how distributions respond to linear transformations, we need only check the $\mu=0,\,\sigma=1$ case, i.e. prove$$\varphi(t):=\exp-\frac12t^2\implies\int_{\Bbb R}\frac{1}{2\pi}\varphi(t)\exp(-itx)dt=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp-\frac{x^2}{2}dx.$$(This integral is the PDF, by the [inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Inversion_formulae).) The proportionality constants boil down to the $\alpha=\frac12$ special case of$$\int_{\Bbb R}\exp(-\alpha y^2)dy=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}.$$Again, verification need only check $\alpha=1$. This has many proofs, the first [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf) being the standard one in textbooks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specific answer why π and Euler (or natural logarithm) but I found a general answer to my question. The hint was found here [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) where they mention function e^(-x^2) and its integral sqrt(π).

Second part of the hint was this page [Normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) where they mention both functions as simplified PDF for variance 1/2 and mean 0.

[image]

Meaning the general form of PDF equals to f(x) / integral of f(x) where f(x) is a distribution function.