# What is the asymptotic behavior of A103213 in OEIS?

Tags: sequences-and-series

It's probably not at all hard—but at least right now it's not obvious to me—how to determine the asymptotic behavior of

$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k}$

([link to OEIS](http://oeis.org/A103213)).

Comment: After plotting, a plausible asymptote seems to be (a constant times) $\exp(2n/3)$. But I am not confident of this.

Comment: We have $$\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}{1\over k} \geq \sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}{1\over k+1} = {2^{n+1}-2-n \over n+1}$$ so $\exp(2/3)$ is too small.

Comment: The OEIS link you gave has the $\sum (2^j -1)/j$ formula...

Comment: @Moron: I see that now, didn't parse the a(n) properly. My apologies.

Comment: No need to apologize :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that $f(n) = \sum_{k=1}^n {n \choose k} \frac{1}{k} = \int_0^1 \frac{(t+1)^n - 1}{t}\, dt = \int_1^2 \frac{s^n - 1}{s-1} \, ds = \sum_{j=1}^{n} \frac{2^{j} - 1}{j}$.
I think the leading term should be $2^{n+1}/n$

Comment: Nice!

Comment: Oh, this is elegant. I'd considered Stirling but got caught up on something. But I didn't anticipate this.

Comment: ... and in fact I get $\frac{2^n}{n} (2 + \frac{2}{n} + \frac{6}{n^2} + \frac{26}{n^3} + \ldots) =$ (formally)
$2^n \sum_{k=1}^\infty (-1)^k \frac{polylog(-k,2)}{n^{k+1}}$

Answer (score 9):

Here's a heuristic argument using probability.

Multiplying the OP's sum by $n/2^n$ gives 
$${1\over 2^n}\sum_{k=1}^n {n\choose k}{n\over k}=E\left({1\over \bar X_n}\right)$$
where $\bar X_n$ is the sample average of $n$ independent Bernoulli random variables with mean $1/2$ and we ignore the outcome $\bar X_n=0$.

By the law of large numbers, $1/\bar X_n\to 2$ almost surely, making it plausible that  the left hand side of the equation above is approximately equal to 2.

Comment: I love this argument!

Comment: This is interesting, thanks.

Comment: @Raskolnikov Thanks. It needs some work to make it rigorous though.

Answer (score 5):

(see the [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29534/how-to-show-that-sum-k-1n-1-frackkn-kn-is-asymptotically-sqrt/29563#29563))

Asymptotically, the sum behaves like the integral $$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k} = \int_1^n dk \, \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)! \,k}.$$ For large $n$, you can approximate the integral by expanding the integrand around its maximum (attained at $k=n/2$). We have (using Stirling) 
$$\log \frac{n!}{k! (n-k)!}  \sim n \log n - k \log k -(n-k) \log (n-k)$$
with the maximum at $k=n/2$. The expansion around $k=n/2$ reads
$$n \log n - k \log k -(n-k) \log (n-k) =  - \frac{2}{n}  (k- n/2)^2.$$
 Thereby, we can approximate
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{k} \sim 
\frac{2}{n}\binom{n}{n/2} \int_1^n dk e^{ -2 (k- n/2)^2/n} \sim \frac{2}{n}
\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n/2}} \sqrt{\frac{\pi n}{2}}
=\frac{2^{n+1}}{n}
,$$
where we used the fact that $\binom{n}{n/2} \sim 2^n/\sqrt{\pi n/2}$.

Comment: Nice, my original thought was to use Stirling but I must have made a mistake en route. Thanks.

Comment: I believe [this problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29442/expected-tail-and-head-length-of-rho-for-a-finite-random-function) allows you to use the same technique.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an exact lower bound, which, as is readily seen, approximately equal to $2^{n+1}/n$.
By Jensen's inequality, since $1/x$ is convex, 
$$
\frac{{\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {{n \choose k}} }}{{\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {{n \choose k}} k}} \leq \frac{{\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k}} }}{{\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^n {{n \choose k}} }}.
$$
From this it follows straightforwardly that
$$
\frac{{(2^n  - 1)^2 }}{{2^{n - 1} n}} \le \sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k}} .
$$

EDIT: Hence,
$$
\sum\limits_{k = 1}^n {{n \choose k}\frac{1}{k}} \geq \frac{{2^{n + 1} }}{n} - \frac{4}{n} + \frac{1}{{2^{n - 1} n}}.
$$

Comment: Another elegant answer!