# $\int e^{-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2)

How does one integrate $\int e^{-x^2}\,dx$? I read somewhere to use polar coordinates.

How is this done? What is the easiest way?

Comment: As an indefinite integral, this is not expressible by elementary functions. I guess you mean a definite integral?

Comment: This is an interesting integral. There is an expository paper by K Conrad dealing with this.

Comment: One of most elementary ways to prove it is using limits and arctangent : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2/1759809#1759809

Side note : On the same page are other solutions as well so check them out :)

Answer (score 7):

You can integrate the function $e^{-x^2}$ only as a definite integral, as you mention you can do it using polar coordinates as follows:

Let $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx$ then multiply it by $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}\,dy$ so we have $I^2 = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx\right) \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2}\,dy\right) = \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x^2 + y^2)}\,dx\,dy\right)$ now we can change this integral to polar coordinates using $ \rho^2 =  x^2 + y^2$ and now $ I^2 = \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\rho^2} \rho \, d\rho \, d\theta = \pi$ and finally $I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2}\,dx = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Answer (score 2):

We had a [nice discussion](http://gowers.wordpress.com/2007/10/04/when-are-two-proofs-essentially-the-same/#comment-239) of different ways to prove this over on Tim Gowers' blog a few years ago.

Answer (score 1):

The function you have mentioned is called the `gaussian integral`.... Read more about it on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). It has explanation regarding solving it by using the polar co-ordinates too ..............