# Strange integrand: $\int \sqrt{x} e^{x}dx$

Tags: integration, gaussian-integral

Is it possible, and if yes, how,  to evaluate an integral like $\int \sqrt{x} e^{x}dx$? I have heard of the Gaussian function which integrates to $\sqrt{\pi}$ but what about this? Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That indefinite integral is not an elementary one: in fact using the substitution $y=\sqrt{x}$ and integrating by parts you obtain:
$$\begin{split}
\int \sqrt{x}\ e^x\ \text{d}x &\stackrel{x=y^2}{=} \int 2y^2\ e^{y^2}\ \text{d} y \\
&= \int y\ \text{d} \left( e^{y^2}\right)\\
&= y\ e^{y^2} -\int e^{y^2}\ \text{d} y
\end{split}$$
where the latter integral is not elementary.

Comment: You could continue to $$\sqrt {x}{{e}^{x}}-{\frac {\sqrt {\pi}}{2}{\rm erfi} \left( \sqrt {x} \right) } + C$$

Answer (score 1):

To get $\sqrt{\pi}$ you need to integrate from $0$ to $\infty$, and you need to replace $e^x$ by $e^{-x}$.  Specifically, we have $$\int_0^\infty \sqrt{x}e^{-x}dx =\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$

See the following answer for a variety of different proofs: [$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx$ with complex analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis/34776#34776)