# How to solve $\int \sqrt{x} e^{x} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration

I can't solve this integral. I have tried all the things that I could think of, but I keep getting stuck.

Comment: https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-int-sqrtx-e-x-dx-using-integration-by-parts#628186

Comment: See also: [Strange integrand: $\int \sqrt{x} e^{x}dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/122888). You can check the search results [from Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%20e%5E%7Bx%7D%20%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dx%24&p=1) and [from SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Cint%20%5Csqrt%7Bx%7D%20e%5E%7Bx%7D%20%5Cmathrm%7Bd%7Dx%7D%24) to see whether you find some other interesting posts there. (I reposted this - the comment was deleted in the migration.)

Comment: the indefinite integral (which is what you want) cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions; it's this function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function