# How to show the normal density integrates to 1?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, polar-coordinates

How could you show that the normal density integrates to 1?

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-(x+\mu)^2 / \sigma^2} dx = 1 $$

Comment: See [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) and [How to prove $ \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2} \; dx = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2$ without changing into polar coordinates?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188241/how-to-prove-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2-without-changi)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$ is a so called [Schwartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space)-function for which you can use [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) in 2-dimension.

It holds:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \exp(-x^2)dx\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-x^2)dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-x^2-y^2)dxdy$$

This can be solved in polar-coordinates easilly and its value is $\pi$.

Because of $\exp(-x^2)\gt0\,\forall\,x$ you have  $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-x^2)\gt0$ and finally $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\exp(-x^2) = \sqrt{\pi}$