# Notable definite integral involving $e$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How could we prove the following equality?

$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\mathrm{e}^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188241/how-to-prove-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2-without-changi

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2

Comment: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral] seems to have some opinions

Answer (score 0):

Hint (you'll find answers everywhere):
$$
I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx\implies I^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\mathrm dy
$$