# Value of an integral related to Stirling's formula

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Consider the following improper integral :
$$
I = \int_1^\infty  \left(\{t\}-\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}.
$$

Comparing with Stirling's formula, we can see that $I = \ln(\sqrt{2\pi}) - 1$. Is there a more direct way to compute this ?

Edit : I have split my two questions : the other part is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264238/limit-of-an-integral-remainder-term-of-a-euler-maclaurin-expansion).

Comment: You have two different questions here.  I think it would be best if you asked two separate questions rather than putting them both into one.

Comment: Your second integral is nothing but the series $$\int_1^{\infty} \left( \{t\} - \dfrac12\right) \dfrac{dt}t = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1} \left(t-n-\dfrac12 \right) \dfrac{dt}t = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1 - (n+1/2) \log(n+1) + (n+1/2) \log n \right)$$

Comment: For $\text{Re}(s)>0,$ we have that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ t\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)t^{-s-1}dt=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{-\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{2}}{s}$$ where $\zeta(s)$ is the Riemann zeta function. Taking the limit as $s\rightarrow0,$ and using the fact that $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2},$ we find that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ t\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}=-\zeta^{'}(0)-1.$$ Since $-\zeta^{'}(0)=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi\right),$ it follows that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ t\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(2\pi\right)-1.$$

Comment: @Marvis : How to use this without Stirling's formula?

Comment: @EricNaslund. None of your equalities seems obvious to me. Do you have any reference that could help with these computations? (I suppose it's from analytic number theory?)

Comment: @EricNaslund I would assume that to obtain $-\zeta'(0) = \dfrac12 \log(2 \pi)$, we need Stirling's formula in some form?

Comment: @Marvis: I don't think we do.  We can use the functional equation and derive it from there.

Comment: @Marvis: Perhaps in some sense you could view what I did as deriving the constant in Stirlings formula in a different way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Riemann zeta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) is defined as $\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{-s}.$ Writing this as a Riemann [Stieltjies integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Stieltjes_integral) and applying integration by parts we have that $$\zeta(s)=\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-s}d\left[x\right]=\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-s}dx-\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-s}d\left\{ x\right\}$$

$$=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_{1}^{\infty}\left\{ x\right\} x^{-s-1}dx,$$ and this holds for all $\text{Re}(s)>0.$ Notice that taking the limit as $s\rightarrow0$  yields $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2}.$ Now, since $\frac{s}{2}\int_{1}^{\infty}x^{-s-1}=\frac{1}{2},$ it follows that $$\zeta(s)+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{s}{s-1}-s\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ x\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)x^{-s-1}dx,$$ and so for $\text{Re}(s)>0,$  we have that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ t\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)t^{-s-1}dt=\frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{-\zeta(s)-\frac{1}{2}}{s}.$$ Taking the limit as $s\rightarrow0,$ and using the fact that $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2},$ we find that $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ t\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}=-\zeta^{'}(0)-1.$$ Since $\zeta^{'}(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)$, this yields $$\int_{1}^{\infty}\left(\left\{ t\right\} -\frac{1}{2}\right)\frac{dt}{t}=\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi)-1,$$ as desired.

**Proving that $\zeta^{'}(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi).$**

Recall the [functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) for the zeta function, $$\zeta(z)=2^{z}\pi^{z-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(1-z\right)\zeta\left(1-z\right).$$ Taking the logarithmic derivative, we have that $$\frac{\zeta^{'}(z)}{\zeta(z)}=\log2+\log\pi-\frac{\Gamma^{'}\left(1-z\right)}{\Gamma\left(1-z\right)}+\frac{d}{dz}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\zeta\left(1-z\right)\right).$$ Since $\zeta(1-z)=-\frac{1}{z}+\gamma+O(z),$ and $\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi z}{2}+O\left(z^{3}\right),$ we have that $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\zeta\left(1-z\right)=\frac{\pi}{2}-\frac{\pi\gamma}{2}z+O\left(z^{2}\right),$$

and so $$\frac{d}{dz}\log\left(\sin\left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)\zeta\left(1-z\right)\right)=\frac{-\frac{\pi\gamma}{2}+O\left(z\right)}{\frac{\pi}{2}+O\left(z\right)}=-\gamma+O(z).$$ Thus $$\frac{\zeta^{'}(0)}{\zeta(0)}=\log2\pi-\Gamma^{'}\left(1\right)-\gamma.$$ As $\Gamma^{'}(1)=-\gamma,$ and $\zeta(0)=-\frac{1}{2},$ we conclude that $$\zeta^{'}(0)=-\frac{1}{2}\log2\pi.$$

**Remark:** This reminded me of my [answer regarding the evaluation of $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right).$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis/34776#34776)

Comment: Nice. I have not seen this before. For some reason, I thought that the functional equation approach might be complicated or might get out of hand, to evaluate the derivative.

Comment: @Marvis: At first I thought the same thing, and I was thinking "ooo no, there are too many terms all multiplied together.  I don't want to take the product rule that many times" but then I remembered the logarithmic derivative is a shortcut out of multi product rule, and it turned out rather nice.