# Complex Analytic Proof of the Gaussian Integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz=\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz=\sqrt{\pi}$.

Here is my attempted solution:

Define $a:=\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$ and let $f(z) = \frac{e^{-z^2}}{1+e^{-2az}}$.

Note that $a^2=\pi i$.

Now $f(z)$ has poles of order 1 at $(k+\frac{1}{2})a$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$.  Thus using the Residue Theorem and l'Hôpital's Rule:

$$\lim_{z\rightarrow (k+\frac{1}{2})a}\frac{(z-(k+\frac{1}{2})a)e^{-z^2}}{1+e^{-2az}}=\lim_{z\rightarrow (k+\frac{1}{2})a}\frac{\frac{d}{dz}(z-(k+\frac{1}{2})a)e^{-z^2}}{\frac{d}{dz}1+e^{-2az}}=\frac{e^{-(k+\frac{1}{2})^2a^2}}{-2ae^{-2(k+\frac{1}{2})a^2}}=\frac{e^{-k^2a^2-ka^2-\frac{a^2}{4}}}{-2ae^{-2ka^2-a^2}}=\frac{e^{-\pi ik^2-\pi ik-\frac{\pi i}{4}}}{-2ae^{-2\pi ik-\pi i}}=\frac{e^{\frac{-\pi i}{4}}}{2\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}i}$$

It can be shown that $f(z)-f(z+a)=e^{-z^2}$ (I wont prove this but it's most definitely true).  I'm going to integrate this function around the contour which is a rhombus slanting to the right whose bottom two corners lie at $-R$ and $R$.  Thus we have:

$$\lim_{R\rightarrow\infty}\bigg[\int_{-R}^{R}f+\int_{R+at}f+\int_{R+a}^{-R+a}f+\int_{R+a(1-t)}f\bigg]=\sum_{k\geq 0}\sqrt{\pi}$$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$.

Making the substitutions $u=z-a$ for the third integral and then $v=1-t$ for the fourth, and then taking $R\rightarrow\infty$, we obtain:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-z^2}dz=\sum_{k\geq 0}\sqrt{\pi}$$

Whew! Ok so clearly all I really want is just one $\sqrt{\pi}$, not an infinite number of them.  But when I take $R\rightarrow\infty$ my rhombus contains all the poles in the upper-half plane.  Can anyone tell where I went wrong?

Comment: $$1+e^{-2az}=0\Longleftrightarrow e^{-2az}=-1\Longleftrightarrow 2az=\frac{2k+1}{2}\pi i\Longleftrightarrow z=\frac{2k+1}{4a}\pi i=:w_k\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z$$

so I don't understand where did you get your function's poles from...or, of course, I missed something.

Comment: The only thing different between mine and yours is you have an extra factor of 2 in the denominator, and I think that might have been a mistake on your part.

Comment: I don't think that's the only difference: you also have $\,a\,$ multiplying, I have it dividing...

Comment: Yes but $a=\sqrt{\pi}e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$, so bringing it up to the numerator and making the powers negative simplifies to $a$ up above, since $i=e^{\frac{\pi i}{2}}$.  Or I guess simpler would be just to refer to my note that $\pi i=a^2$.

Comment: Oh, I forgot the definition of $\,a\,$...yes, indeed. Well, that factor of two in the denominator still can make some important difference when evaluating the residues. Check this

Comment: Something I'm not completely confident about is are these poles in fact of order 1?

Comment: Yes they are, otherwise the limit wouldn't be non-zero and finite...

Comment: Ok that makes sense

Comment: Actually, a guy finally found a way to do this integral by residues fairly directly. The figure used was not a rectangle with edges parallel to the real and imaginary axes, it was a parallelogram with two edges parallel to the real axis. Nobody ever found a way with a rectangle. I believe it appeared in the M.A.A. Monthly. Which leads to the question, why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @WillJagy That's probably the same contour I'm using, it is a parallelogram(rhombus), not a rectangle.  It's definitely doable anyways, since the contour is given to me explicitly in my book.

Comment: See this also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis

Comment: Ok, take a peek here http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ , proof 8 (page 6). The proof is pretty fleshed out, and you can find it also in Remmert's "Theory of Complex Functions"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok everyone you can stop furiously scribbling to check all my calculations.  Byron Schmuland sent me to a post which has this same solution and it made me realize my mistake:

Taking $R\rightarrow\infty$ only extends this rhombus in the horizontal directions!  So I don't pick up anymore singularities in the limit.  So there it is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a proof which is not at all 'Complex Analytic' but is very elementary so I thought of sharing it as an answer to this question.

Let $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=z$. Clearly $z=2\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx$. Now as exponential function is positive so we have, $z\geq 0$(It is rather strict)

Then we have $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy=z^2$

We have,

$$z^2=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx.\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}dxdy=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x+y)^2}dxdy$$

Changing into the polar co-ordinates we have,

$$x=r\cos \theta,y=r \sin \theta$$
$$\Rightarrow dxdy=rdrd\theta$$

Replacing in the above integral we have,

$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta$$

$$= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y}dyd\theta$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}d\theta$$
$$=\pi$$

So we have ,

$$z^2=\pi$$

$$\Rightarrow z=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: What do you mean by "exponential function positive"? Complex function can be neither positive nor negative, since positivity is something related to real numbers only. Also, what exactly do you mean by introducing polar coordinates for complex number $z = x + iy$? Anyway, point is proof you provided is for real numbers.

Comment: Yes the proof is for real numbers.

Comment: Right. But it supposed to be proved for complex numbers :)