# How to integrate $\displaystyle 1-e^{-1/x^2}$?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

> How to integrate $\displaystyle 1-e^{-1/x^2}$ ?
>
> as hint is given: $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb R}e^{-x^2/2}=\sqrt{2\pi}$

If i substitute $u=\dfrac{1}{x}$, it doesn't bring anything:

$\,\displaystyle\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-1/x^2}\right)dx=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{0}\left(1-e^{-1/x^2}\right)dx+\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-e^{-1/x^2}\right)dx\overset{?}=2\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{e^{-u^2}}{-u^2}\right)du$

$2\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{e^{-u^2}}{-u^2}\right)du=?$

How to continue ?

$\textbf{The original exercise was}$:

If a probability has a density $f(x)=C(1-e^{-1/x^2})$ then determine the value of constant $C$

Since $\displaystyle\int f\overset{!}=1$, i thought first to calculate the expression above.

($\textbf{ATTENTION:}$ Question edited from integrating $e^{-1/x^2}$ to integrating
$1-e^{-1/x^2}$)

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis).

Comment: @Git Gud No gamma function please.

Comment: the  value of the integral $ \int_{0}^{\infty} e ^{- u^2}$ is $\sqrt{\pi} / 2$ , if i dont forget. (but i dont remenber how to evaluate ))

Comment: In your integration by parts, you incorrectly calculated the boundary term to be zero. It's actually infinite, and so your integral diverges.

Comment: @derivative there is one easy way to evaluate the above integral using double integrals

Comment: @DavidH you mean $2e^{-u^2}\frac{1}{u}\Biggr|_0^{\infty}=\infty$

Comment: @derivative:  your integral is infinite, as the integrand goes to $1$ at both ends of the interval.  Do you mean to integrate $\exp(-x^2)$?  That one is finite.  See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2/9292#9292)

Comment: You definitely need to integrate $1-\exp(\frac {-1}{x^2})$  That one converges.  It looks like you should be able to transform it to something involving $\exp(-x^2)$ because the answer is $2\sqrt \pi$ from [Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%281-exp%28-1%2Fx%5E2%29%29+from+-infinity+to+infinity)

Comment: @2012ssohn When I edited question I set $e^{-1/x^2}$ because $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ looks to small to my eyes (that $x$ looks like $z$ in second variant). Now, I see that is again $e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$. I just want to say that.

Comment: @Cortizol - Sorry about that. Looks like our revisions were submitted almost simultaneously. Less than a second apart, as a matter of fact! I'll edit that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First integrate by part and then substitute $x$ by $1/y$.
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty (1-e^{-1/x^2})dx &= 
\left[(1-e^{-1/x^2})x\right]_0^\infty - \int_0^\infty x \left(-\frac{2}{x^3}\right) e^{-1/x^2} dx\\
&= 2\int_0^\infty e^{-y^2} dy = \sqrt{\pi}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: That's it, just integration by parts. but limits are from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ then everything is ok.

Comment: @derivative The $-\infty$ to $\infty$ part is trivial because the integrand is an even function. To make this completely rigorous, you just need to justify why $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-e^{-1/x^2})x = 0$ and that's it.

Comment: yes, i mean only for the result,

Comment: This deserves +50. Of course. +1 upvote!

Answer (score 6):

Here is another technique of *introducing a parameter*. Indeed, let us consider the integral

$$ I(s) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1 - e^{-s/x^{2}}) \, dx $$

instead. We then want to find the value if $I(1)$. To this end, we calculate $I'(s)$ and appeal to the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

We first simplify $I(s)$ by using change of variable. Let $u = 1/x$. Then by symmetry,

$$ I(s) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} (1 - e^{-s/x^{2}}) \, dx = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1 - e^{-su^{2}}}{u^{2}} \, du. $$

Then we differentiate both sides with respect to $s$. Exploiting Leibniz's integral rule yields

$$ I'(s) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\partial}{\partial s} \frac{1 - e^{-su^{2}}}{u^{2}} \, du = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-su^{2}} \, du. $$

Now with the additional substitution $v = \sqrt{2s}u$ (where $s > 0$), we have

$$ I'(s) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{s}} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-v^{2}/2} \, dv = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2s}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-v^{2}/2} \, dv = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}}. $$

But it is trivial that $I(0) = 0$ (since the integrand vanishes identically). Therefore by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus,

$$ I(1) = I(0) + \int_{0}^{1} I'(s) \, ds = \int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{s}} \, ds = \left. 2\sqrt{\pi s} \vphantom{\int} \right|_{0}^{1} = 2\sqrt{\pi}. $$

Comment: @achillehui, Thank you! Writing in $\TeX$ is always sort of multitasking, and it often leads me to make some typos. :(

Comment: looks nice, but if $u=1/x$ then $du=-1/x^2dx=-u^2dx$ you forgot the sign, but this doesn't change anything.

Comment: @derivative when one substitute $u = 1/x$, the extra minus sign in $du$ is canceled when you flip the integration limits back from $\int_{\infty}^0$ to $\int_0^{\infty}$.

Comment: @achillehui aha didn't noticed. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What is $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}e^{{-1}/{x^2}}$ ?

Comment: I really don't see how this helps in *evaluating* the integral.

Comment: @Sabyasachi i think he is telling about the boundary term which is infinite but in the question he made it zero

Comment: @happymath still the original integral remains unsolved. this points out a flaw in the current process. Doesn't show an alternative though.

Comment: Oh wait the integral diverges. I see.

Comment: @Sabyasachi you are right and also the integral diverges that is what i guess he wants to tell

Answer (score 1):

$\int\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx$

$=\int\left(1-\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{-2n}}{n!}\right)dx$

$=\int-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{-2n}}{n!}dx$

$=-\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^nx^{1-2n}}{n!(1-2n)}+c$

$=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n-1)x^{2n-1}}+c$

$\because\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx$

$=\int_{-\infty}^0\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx+\int_0^\infty\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx$

$=\int_\infty^0\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{(-x)^2}}\right)d(-x)+\int_0^\infty\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx$

$=\int_0^\infty\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx+\int_0^\infty\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx$

$=2\int_0^\infty\left(1-e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)dx$

$=2\int_\infty^0\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)d\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$

$=2\left[\dfrac{1-e^{-x^2}}{x}\right]_\infty^0-2\int_\infty^0\dfrac{1}{x}d\left(1-e^{-x^2}\right)$

$=4\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}~dx$

$=2\sqrt\pi$

$\therefore C=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt\pi}$

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for your efforts, but i had to change the problem, it was a mistake of me.

Comment: So you edited it. I think you did everything correct, and came close to the result, but something is missing...

Answer (score 0):

The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-1/x^2)dx$$diverges, because $\exp(-1/x^2)\ge \frac 1e$ whenever $|x|>1$ and hence 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(-1/x^2)dx> 2\int_1^\infty \frac{dx}{e}=+\infty. $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^\infty\bigg(1-e^{^{-\tfrac1{x^2}}}\bigg)dx=\sqrt\pi.$$ This can relatively easily be proven by letting $t=e^{^{-\tfrac1{x^2}}}$, and then using Euler's [initial logarithmic expression for the $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History). But you said that this is apparently not allowed and I'm afraid that I don't know any other approaches either. :-(

Comment: everything is allowed, but i don't think that i will understand it.

Comment: The first part of your sentence sounds kinda funny when taken out of context. :-) As for the second part, might [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2/531436#531436) be of any help ?

Comment: Interesting but i still can't see it.