# Closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{- n^2} z^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form, theta-functions

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761856/sum-n-infty-infty-e-alpha-n2-beta-n) the summation goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and the answer has a pretty "good" closed form.

Now I came across the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{-n^2} z^n$ where $|z|<1$ and I don't know how to crack it.

Please help me!

Comment: That can be expressed in terms of the Jacobi theta function: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Auxiliary_functions. That’s about as close to a closed form as you can get

Comment: Jakobi functions work well when the lower bound of summation is $-\infty$. Instead I'm interested in sum starting from 1

Comment: The sum can be expressed in terms of [basic hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series), concretely as $_0\phi_1 \left[0;\frac{1}{q},\frac{z}{q}\right] -1$. I don't know if a simpler form exists.

Comment: @pregunton I've read some articles about basic hypergeometric functions but I didn't understand what the general form of $_0 \phi_1$ looks like. Could you express it as a sum?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake, what I meant is $_1\phi_2$. We have $-1+{}_1\phi_2\left[ \begin{matrix} 1/q\\0\;\;0 \end{matrix}\:;\frac{1}{q},\frac{z}{q}\right] = -1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(1/q;1/q)_n}{(0,0,1/q;1/q)_n}\left((-1)^n \frac{1}{q^{n \choose 2}} \right)^{1+2-1}\left(\frac{z}{q}\right)^n$. The first fraction equals 1 because the $q$-shifted factorials cancel (the definition of $q$-shifted factorial is given in the article I linked), and simplifying the remaining terms we end up with $-1+\sum_{n=0}^\infty q^{-n^2}z^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{-n^2}z^n$.

Comment: Since I haven't found enough information about this particular function (it could happen not because of lack of information but just because I looked into wrong sources) I will accept your answer and give all the bounty if you express $_1\phi_2$ in terms of $_r\phi_s$ where $r>s$. Those functions are widely studied... I hope that such expression do exist!