# Residue calculus: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, residue-calculus

I am pretty sure I have read the answer somewhere on this site, but sadly I am unable to find the question.

How to evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x$ using the residue theorem?

Comment: Try the answers given to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34767/int-infty-infty-e-x2-dx-with-complex-analysis

Comment: @Bacon: Thanks a lot :)