# Showing that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving $\\int_{0}^{+\\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \\frac{\\sqrt \\pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2)

The primitive of $f(x) = \exp(-x^2)$ has no analytical expression, even so, it is possible to evaluate $\int f(x)$ along the whole real line with a few tricks. How can one show that 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(-x^2) \,\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi} \space ?
$$

Comment: @Ross Millikan Damn, that one didn't show up in the related questions. It *is* quite a duplicate, the only difference is a predictable symmetry argument to double the answer. This question will probably be deleted. Oh, well.

Comment: The related question searcher seems to be spotty.  I am surprised both by what it finds and by what it misses.  No problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such an integral is called a [Gaussian Integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_a_Gaussian_function) link should help you out.