# How can I show that these two integrals are equal?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

How can I show that there is an equality
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\right)?
$$

Comment: You can change the variable of integration in one of your integrals on the right-hand side from x to, e.g., y. Then $e^{-y^2}$ is a constant with respect to x.

Comment: Are you asking for the formal manipulations to go from one side to the other side? Or are you asking for the mathematical justification for the steps of the manipulations?

Comment: Why did no one mention [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can separate them as follows

$$
\begin{align*}
\iint e^{-x^2 - y^2} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y & = \iint e^{-x^2} e^{-y^2} \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y\\
& = \int \left ( e^{-y^2} \int e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x \right  )  \mathrm{d}y\\ 
&= \left ( \int e^{-x^2} \mathrm{d}x \right ) \left(  \int e^{-y^2} \mathrm{d}y   \right )
\end{align*}
$$

Just in case, I will mention that whenever you have a double integral of the form

$$\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} f(x) g(y) \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x$$

you can separate it as a product of two integrals

$$
\int_{a}^{b} \int_{c}^{d} f(x) g(y) \mathrm{d}y \mathrm{d}x = \left ( \int _{a}^{b} f(x) \mathrm{d}x  \right )  \left ( \int _{c}^{d} g(y) \mathrm{d}y  \right )
$$

in the same way as before.

Comment: use $\text{align}$ environment

Comment: @Chandru Yes that would correct the problem of the formulas overflowing. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: No problem :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint for the most reasonable way:
1) $e^{a + b} = e^a e^b$
2) Remember that the x and the y are just 'dummy' variables

I should also point you to an old [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2) by Ross, which I can only imagine is the cause of this question.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - x^2  - y^2 } dx} dy}  = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - y^2 } \bigg(\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - x^2 } dx} \bigg)dy}  = \bigg(\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - x^2 } dx} \bigg)\bigg(\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {e^{ - y^2 } dy} \bigg).$$

EDIT: It may be worth noting that there is a distinction between an iterated integral and a double integral. However, for any nonnegative measurable function $f(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$, it holds
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}} {f(x,y)dxdy}  = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\bigg(\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f(x,y)dx} \bigg)dy}  = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\bigg(\int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {f(x,y)} dy\bigg)dx} .
$$
The first integral is a double integral, the last two are iterated integrals.

Comment: The above holds regardless of whether the integrals are finite.

Comment: Of course, the situation is much simpler when $f$ is of the form $f(x,y)=g(x)h(y)$.