# Improper integral with discontinuity

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Determine if
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}dx$$
is convergent or not.

Since the function is discontinous at $x=0$, I cannot apply comparison theorems for improper integrals. I have tried taking the integral to evaluate the limits but I couldn't do it because there is a problem with exponential of $e$.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Discontinuous at $0$? Why do you say that?

Comment: @zhw. because the denominator is $x^2?$

Comment: Isn't it possible that the integrand has a nice finite limit at $0$?

Comment: Yes it can but I still don't get it.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $t=\dfrac1x$

Comment: @Lucian I tried but I get $e^{-t^{2}}$

Comment: But convert the whole integrand, including the division by $x^2$ which then becomes multiplication by $t^2.$

Comment: @rackne: What do you mean “but” ? Obviously, $e^{-t^2}$ is an exponential function which decreases at an even more powerful rate than $e^{-t}$, so if the integral of the latter converges, then so does that of the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform the substitution $u = \frac{1}{x}$ on $\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}}{x^2}\;dx$. So $-du = \frac{1}{x^2}dx$ and $-\int_{\infty}^{0}e^{-u^2}\;du$. We recognize this is just $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}\;du$. We know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}\;du = \sqrt{\pi}$ and by the symmetry of $e^{-u^2}$ that the area under x-axis is the same on either side, thus $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}\;du = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$.

Comment: In the untransformed integral, integrand is positive on $[0,\infty).$ Yet your calculation gives the value as negative...

Comment: Fixed, screwed up the u-sub in the beginning so the sign was off.

Comment: Where do we know that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-u^2}\;du = \sqrt{\pi}$?

Comment: Connor Harris in his answer gives a basic idea on how to find the integral. The trick is to square the result and then interpret it at as a double integral. You can then re-express the region in polar coordinates and then evaluate that integral, which is very simple, and then take the square root of the result. The answer is $\sqrt{\pi}$ and is hard to evaluate without a knowledge of multivariable calculus.

Comment: Thanks @Tyg13 but the question is asked in a single variable course they wouldn't expect us to find the answer in this way.

Comment: @rackne, once you perform the desired substitution, we can use regular methods to determine whether or not the transformed integral converges. If it converges, we know the original integral converges as well. Transforming the integral removes the discontinuity at 0, so we can use standard methods to check if it converges. See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96840/does-the-improper-integral-int-0-infty-e-x2dx-converge)

Comment: @Tyg13 now that is nice solution to me thanks

Answer (score 1):

As Lucian hints in commments, with the change of variables $$t = \frac{1}{x}, dt = -\frac{dx}{x^2}$$ this integral becomes $$\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\, dt$$ which does converge, and in fact equals $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$. There is a standard trick to evaluating integrals of this sort: for the more usual example $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx$, write $$\left( \int e^{-x^2}\, dx\right)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\, dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\, dy = \iint_{\mathbf{R}^2} e^{-x^2 - y^2}\, dx\, dy$$
and then change to polar coordinates: $$\iint_{\mathbf{R}^2} e^{-x^2 - y^2}\, dx\, dy = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty e^{-r^2} (r\, dr)\, d\theta$$
and this last integral can be done easily.

Comment: We haven't learnt double integrals yet. I don't understand after $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\, dt$. There must be an easy way

Comment: Unfortunately $e^{-t^2}$ has no antiderivative that is expressible with elementary functions, so we cannot find a general expression for the integral so we can evaluate it.

Answer (score 0):

Briefly: For convergence we only need to check that $\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}\, dx$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}\, dx$ both converge. In the first integral, the integrand $\to 0$ at $0.$ So the integrand is bounded on $(0,1]$ and there is no trouble at all. For the second integral, the integrand is positive and bounded above by $\frac{1}{x^2}.$ Since $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2}\, dx <\infty,$ we're OK here as well. It foll0ws that $\int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^2}\, dx$ converges.