# Definite integral resolution

Tags: calculus, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proving $\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2)

My calculus is a bit rusty, how should I solve this in order to calculate the solution?

$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}e^{-x^{2}}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$

Comment: This is surely a duplicate. I'll see if I can find a previous version.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know how to find the same formula

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if $I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}$ then 
$$I^2=\int\int e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=\int\int re^{-r^2}drd\theta=\pi$$