# Why is $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$?

Tags: analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

It seems as if no one has asked this here before, unless I don't know how to search.

The Gamma function is
$$
\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,dx.
$$
Why is
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}\text{ ?}
$$
(I'll post my own answer, but I know there are many ways to show this, so post your own!)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2

Comment: @Argon Did you look at the other question?  It's not even close to the same thing.  And, how on earth did 2 other people vote to close without even looking at it?

Comment: @Graphth With a simply change of variables ($x^2 = t$), the integrals are virtually identical, except for a constant coefficient.

Comment: Maybe not that question, but I am quite sure this has been asked before...

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/.../gaussianintegral.pdf is a good source of methods to solve this.

Answer (score 62):

One can use the trick with spherical coordinates:
$$
   \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x} \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{x}} = \int_0^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x} \mathrm{d} (2 \sqrt{x}) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-u^2} \, \mathrm{d} u
$$
Then:
$$
  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)  = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} \mathrm{e}^{-y^2} \, \mathrm{d}x \, \mathrm{d} y = \underbrace{\int_0^\infty r \mathrm{e}^{-r^2} \, \mathrm{d} r}_{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot \underbrace{\int_{0}^{2\pi} \, \mathrm{d} \phi}_{2 \pi} = \pi
$$

Alternatively one can use the second Euler's integral:
$$
   \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)  \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) }{\Gamma(1)} = \int_0^1 t^{-1/2} (1-t)^{-1/2} \mathrm{d}t = \int_0^1 \mathrm{d} \left(2\arcsin\left(\sqrt{t}\right)\right) = \pi
$$
Now, using $\Gamma(1) = 1$ the result follows.

Yet another method is to use the duplication identity:
$$
   \Gamma(2s) = \frac{2^{2s-1}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma(s) \Gamma\left(s+\frac{1}{2}\right)
$$
at $ s= \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Just a note: Usually these are called polar coordinates (2D) rather than spherical coordinates (3D).

Answer (score 61):

We only need Euler's formula:

$$\Gamma(1-z) \Gamma(z) = \frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z} \Longrightarrow \Gamma^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right ) = \pi $$

Comment: @DonAntonio , Have you any source which prove Euler's formula which you have used  ?

Comment: @MathsLover, there must be thousands as that is a rather well known formula (Euler's Reflection Formula). Check the following: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function , http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html (41) , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula , http://planetmath.org/eulerreflectionformula , http://aw.twi.tudelft.nl/~koekoek/documents/wi4006/gammabeta.pdf (formula 18, page 7) , etc.

Comment: Euler's formula is much more advanced than evaluating $\Gamma(1/2)$.

Comment: @Matt Stun Please be way more careful before you attempt to edit someone else's **answer** : no square root is necessary in the last expression !

Comment: @FawzyHegab: There is a local (MSE) proof of Euler's Reflection Formula in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/176216).

Answer (score 29):

If there's any justice in the universe, someone must have asked here how to show that
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = \sqrt{2\pi}.
$$
Let's suppose that has been answered here.  Let (capital) $X$ be a random variable whose probability distribution is
$$
\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\,dx.
$$
Consider the problem of finding $\operatorname{E}(X^2)$.  It is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/2}\,dx = \text{(by symmetry)} \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty x^2 e^{-x^2/2}\,dx
$$
$$
\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty xe^{-x^2/2}\Big(x\,dx\Big) = \sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^\infty \sqrt{u}\  e^{-u}\,du = \sqrt{\frac2\pi}\  \Gamma\left(\frac32\right) = \frac12\sqrt{\frac2\pi} \Gamma\left(\frac12\right).
$$
So it is enough to show that this expected value is $1$.  That is true if the sum of two independent copies of it has expected value $2$.  So:
$$
\Pr\left(X^2+Y^2<w\right) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\iint\limits_\mathrm{disk}
e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}\,dx\,dy
$$
where the disk has radius $\sqrt{w}$.  This equals
$$
\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\sqrt{w}}  e^{-\rho^2/2}  \,\rho\,d\rho\,d\theta = \int_0^{\sqrt{w}}  e^{-\rho^2/2}  \,\rho\,d\rho.
$$
This last equality holds because we are integrating with respect to $\theta$ something not depending on $\theta$.  Differentiating this with respect to $w$ gives the probability density function of the random variable $X^2+Y^2$:
$$
e^{-w/2}\sqrt{w}\frac{1}{2\sqrt{w}} = \frac{e^{-w/2}}{2}\text{ for }w>0.
$$
So
$$
\operatorname{E}(X^2+Y^2) = \int_0^\infty w \frac{e^{-w/2}}{2}\,dw =2.
$$

Comment: If $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2/2}\,du = \sqrt{2\pi}$ is given, then it seems much simpler to take $\Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{-1/2} \exp(-x) dx$, substitute $u^2=2x$, and we are done.

Answer (score 24):

**Method 1:**
$$\Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^{\infty} x^{-1/2} \exp(-x) dx$$ Set $x = t^2$, to get $$\Gamma(1/2) = \int_0^{\infty} 2\exp(-t^2) dt = \sqrt{\pi}$$

**Method 2:**
$$\beta(x,y) = \dfrac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$
Take $y=x=1/2$, to get $$\beta(1/2,1/2) = \dfrac{\Gamma^2(1/2)}{\Gamma(1)} \implies \Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\beta(1/2,1/2)}$$

$$\beta(x,y) = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^{2x-1}(\theta) \cos^{2y-1}(\theta) d \theta$$
Hence, $$\beta(1/2,1/2) = 2 \int_0^{\pi/2} d \theta = \pi$$
$$\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how did $\frac 1 t$ become 2 in method 1?

Comment: @Hassan dx  = 2t dt ; this term cancels out 1/t and leaves 2.

Answer (score 21):

I'm surprised that no one has mentioned that this $\sqrt{\pi}$ is also "the same one" as the $\sqrt{\pi}$ in Stirling's formula.

It is a known fact that $\Gamma$ is uniquely characterized as the function that satisfies the equation $\Gamma(z+1) = z \Gamma(z)$ and whose logarithm "has nice asymptotics at $+\infty$". The conventional way to explain what "nice asymptotics" should mean in this context involves logarithmic convexity, but I prefer to leave it like this: any function that satisfies that functional equation must coincide with $\Gamma(z)$ up to a periodic factor, which, if nontrivial, would prevent it from having an asymptotic expansion at $+\infty$ in terms of powers and logs.

Now let's turn to [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and assume that it holds both for integer and half-integer values of $\Gamma$. Clearly,

$$\Gamma(n+1/2) = \Gamma(1/2) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{3}{2} \cdot \dots \cdot \frac{2n-1}{2} = \Gamma(1/2) \cdot \frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n!},$$

which is basically the duplication formula. Now if we plug it into the Stirling's formula, we will find out that $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt{\pi}$.

Answer (score 13):

It also follows from the famous [Riemann functional equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function#The_functional_equation) with $s=1/2$:
$$
\zeta(s) = 2^s\pi^{s-1}\ \sin\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)\ \Gamma(1-s)\ \zeta(1-s)
$$
but Euler's reflection formula is probably more basic.

Answer (score 12):

This is a "proof". We know that the surface area of the $n-1$ dimensional unit sphere is 
$$
|S^{n-1}| = \frac{2\pi^{\frac{n}2}}{\Gamma(\frac{n}2)}.
$$
On the other hand, we know that $|S^2|=4\pi$, which gives
$$
4\pi = \frac{2\pi^{\frac32}}{\Gamma(\frac32)} = \frac{2\pi^{\frac32}}{\frac12\Gamma(\frac12)}.
$$

Comment: This formula also holds for $n = 1$ if you take counting measure as your $0$-dimensional measure.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few details missing (showing the integral converges, justifying the differentiation under the integral sign, and so forth), but the main idea should be clear.

Consider the Fourier transform of $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$.

$$\hat f(\xi)= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} e^{-2\pi i x\xi}   \ dx =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} (\cos(2\pi x \xi) - i \sin(2\pi  x \xi)) dx  =\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \cos(2\pi x \xi)  \ dx$$

Differentiate under the integral sign and integrate by parts.

$$\hat f'(\xi) =-2\pi \int e^{-x^2}\sin(2\pi \xi x) \ dx = -2\pi^2 \xi \int e^{-x^2} \cos(2\pi x \xi)  \ dx = -2\pi^2\xi \hat f(\xi)$$

Separate variables.

$$\frac{\hat f'(\xi)}{\hat f(\xi) }= -2\pi^2 \xi \Rightarrow \hat f(\xi) =Ce^{-\pi^2 \xi^2}.$$

Use the inversion formula and change variables .

$$e^{-x^2} = C\int  e^{-\pi^2 \xi^2} \cos(2\pi x \xi) \ d\xi = \frac{C}{\pi} \int  e^{- \xi^2} \cos(2 x \xi) \ d\xi $$

$$e^{-\pi^2 x^2}\frac{C}{\pi} =\int  e^{- \xi^2} \cos(2 x\pi  \xi) \ d\xi =\frac{C^2}{\pi}e^{-\pi^2x^2}\Rightarrow C=\sqrt{\pi}$$

$$\hat f (0) = \sqrt{\pi} = \int e^{-x^2} \cos(0) \ dx = \int e^{-x^2}  \ dx.$$

Answer (score 6):

$$B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^{2}}{\Gamma{(1)}}=\left[\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^{2}$$
$$B\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin{\frac{\pi}{2}}}=\pi$$

Chris.

Comment: For those who find the second line not obvious, here is an elementary explanation: by definition, $B(\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}) = \intop_0^1 x^{1/2} (1-x)^{1/2} dx$, and the graph of $x^{1/2} (1-x)^{1/2}$ is a semicircle, so this directly relates to $\pi$ being defined via the area of the circle. This allows to calculate $\Gamma(\frac{3}{2})$, which is just $\frac{1}{2} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})$

Answer (score 6):

The Gamma function is
$$\Gamma(\alpha)=\int_0^\infty x^{\alpha-1} e^{-x}\,dx$$

Therefore

$$\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) =\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} e^{-x}\,dx$$

Thus, after the change of variable $t=\sqrt{x}$, this turns into the Euler integral
$$t=\sqrt{x} \implies x = t^2$$
$$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} = \frac{1}{2t} \iff dx = 2t\,dt$$

We have
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{t} e^{-t^2}\,2t\,dt = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt $$

And following holds:
$$\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right) = 2\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt$$

Which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt$ is the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). It follows:

$$\left[ \Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2 =  \bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-x^2} dx\bigg)\bigg(\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} e^{-y^2} dy\bigg)$$
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)} \,dx\,dy$$

Now change to polar coordinates
$$\int_0^{+2 \pi}\int_0^{+\infty}e^{-r^2} r\,dr\,d\theta$$

The $\theta$ integral just gives $2\pi$, while the $r$ integral succumbs to the substitution $u=r^2$
$$\left[ \Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)\right]^2 =  2\pi\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u} \,du/2=\pi$$ 
$$\Gamma\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Comment: You are 5 years late my friend. [Sasha](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/215363/272831) already has this in his/her answer.

Comment: Rather than computing $\dfrac{dt}{dx}$ and then deducing $2t\,dt=dx$ from that, I would differentiate both sides of $t^2 = x$ to get $2t\,dt = dx. \qquad$

Answer (score 3):

By the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem),

$$\Gamma(1/2)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n(n!)}{(1/2)(-1/2)\dots(1/2-n)}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt n4^{n+1}(n!)^2}{(2n)!(n+\frac12)}$$

Apply the [Stirling approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) and watch almost everything simplify!

$$\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+\frac12}=\sqrt\pi$$