# Wonder how to evaluate this factorial $\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factorial

I've learned factorial. But today I saw a question which I don't know how to start with:

$$\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!$$

Can anyone explain how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: If you take $a!$ to mean $\Gamma(a+1)$, then this is $\Gamma(1/2) = \sqrt \pi$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: You'll have to use the extension of the factorial which is the [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) : 
[$$\left (-\frac{1}{2}\right )!:=\Gamma\left (\frac{1}{2}\right )=\sqrt{\pi}.$$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by Workaholic,
$$I=\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)!=\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}x^{-1/2}e^{-x}\,dx = 2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}\,dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}\,dy $$
and by Fubini's theorem:
$$ I^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(y^2+z^2)}\,dy\,dz = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\rho\, e^{-\rho^2}\,d\rho\,d\theta = \pi \int_{0}^{+\infty}2\rho\, e^{-\rho^2}\,d\rho = \color{red}{\pi} $$
so:

> $$ \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)! = \color{red}{\sqrt{\pi}}. $$