# Choosing $n$ and $r$ so that $n \choose r$ approximates $\pi$

Tags: combinatorics, special-functions, factorial, pi

I came across a curious formula, while trying out different numbers in $n \choose r$.

$${7.5 \choose 7} \approx \pi $$

The occurrence of $\pi$ with factorials has been discussed before, such as is in [Why is $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi)

Using the gamma function or some other method, can we prove this approximate formula for $7.5 \choose 7$ ?

Also, is there any choice of $n$ and $r$ that yields $\pi$ exactly?

Comment: Well, some value "out there" must be close to $\pi$, right?

Comment: I was excited when I first saw it, thinking it was exactly pi, but then I realized it was just close to it. So yeah, it might just be a coincidence.

Comment: $$\binom{n+1/2}{m}$$ is a rational number for every $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$, hence it cannot equal $\pi$ *exactly*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a coincidence!
$$\binom{7.5}{7}=\binom{7.5}{0.5} = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)\Gamma(8)}=\pi\cdot\left(\frac{16}{\pi\cdot 4^8}\binom{16}{8}\right)
$$ 
hence $\binom{7.5}{7}\approx \pi$ is equivalent to
$$ \frac{16}{\pi\cdot 4^8}\binom{16}{8}\approx 1$$
that is a consequence of
$$ \frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}\approx\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}},\qquad \frac{16}{\pi\sqrt{8\pi}}\approx 1 $$
so our approximation is essentially equivalent to $\pi^3\approx 32$, that follows from
$$ \frac{\pi^3}{32}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3} $$
proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/850442/an-interesting-identity-involving-powers-of-pi-and-values-of-etas). Actually, the last identity implies the tighter (and somewhat nicer) approximation
$$ \pi \approx 31^{1/3}. $$