# Proof of $\Gamma(\frac12)=\sqrt{\pi}$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates, gamma-function

I'm reading this proof of $\Gamma(\frac12)=\sqrt{\pi}$, but I just can't understand this part.

$$\left[{\Gamma(\frac12)}\right]^2=4\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty{e^{-(u^2+v^2)}}dvdu=4\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_0^\infty{e^{-r^2}rdrd{\theta}}$$

I think it is something about polar coordinates but unclear. I would really appreciate if someone could give me a clear explanation. Thank you :)

Comment: Exactly: make a change of variables $u = r\cos\theta$, $v =r\sin \theta$.

Comment: I thought so but I'm still not sure how I should change the range when I make a change of variable in double integrals. Also I'm not sure how to deal with $d(rsin{\theta})d(rcos{\theta})$

Comment: And note that the region covered is the first quadrant. In rectangular coordinates, this is $(x,y)\in (0,\infty)\times(0,\infty)$, but in polar coordinates it is $(r,\theta)\in(0,\infty)\times(0,\pi/2)$.

Comment: One has $dA=dx \; dy =r \; dr\; d\theta$

Comment: $\theta$ ranges in $(0,\pi/2)$ and $r$ in $(0,\infty)$, as in your formula. The Jacobian of the change of variables I wrote above is $r$, hence the result. If this is new to you, you should read about the change of variables formula.

Comment: @Dimen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables

Comment: It meant $\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})dxdy= \int_0^\infty 2\pi r f(r)dr$

Comment: @Dimen Instead of deleting the post, you can post a solution to your own question if you understood what to do. This has the advantage that it will help future visitors to the site.

Comment: (Given your reputation score I am not sure if you can just yet answer posts, but I have given you an upvote in good faith, so that you eventually can.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$ ?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi)