# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{-ax^2}dx$ by using Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

**Evaluate  $\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{-ax^2}dx$ by using Gamma function**

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{-ax^2}dx$$

*Solution:*$$ \text{Let} \\x^2=t\implies 2xdx=dt\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2x}\implies dx=\frac{dt}{2\sqrt t}$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{-at}\frac{1}{2\sqrt t}dt$$

$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{-at}t^{1/2-1}dt$$

what should be the next step?

Comment: Note that $$a^x=e^{\ln(a)x}$$ then use the gamma function definition

Comment: What definition do you use for the "Gamma function"?

Comment: @user:https://www.britannica.com/science/gamma-function

Comment: @P.Styles: For the next step, can you compare the $I$ you got to the form of the Gamma function? The answer is almost there.

Comment: @user:$\sqrt \pi /(ln 2^a)^{1/2}$??

Comment: I think the gaussian integral/error function is more applicable than the gamma function if you use @TymaGaidash method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your integral is just
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-a\log(2)x^2}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a\log 2}}.$$

Comment: This is the error function (+1)

Comment: I would rather call that the Gauss integral!

Answer (score 3):

Starting from where you left off:

> $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}2^{-at}t^{1/2-1}dt$$

$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(\ln(2^{-at}))t^{\frac12-1}dt=\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at\ln(2)}t^{\frac12-1}dt $$

while the gamma function may be defined as:

$$\Gamma(x)\mathop=^\text{def}\int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t} dt$$

Now try $$at\ln(2)=x\implies dt=\frac{dx}{a\ln(2)}$$

with the bounds remaining the same for defined $a\ne0$:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-at\ln(2)}t^{\frac12-1}dt = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}\left(\frac x{a\ln(2)}\right)^{-\frac12}\frac {dx}{a\ln(2)}= \frac1{\sqrt{a\ln(2)}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{\frac12-1}dx=\sqrt{\frac\pi{a\ln(2)}}$$
with

> [$$\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\sqrt \pi  $$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/215352/why-is-gamma-left-frac12-right-sqrt-pi)