# How to integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2}} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate this?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-(x-y)^2}{2}} dx$$

Comment: Relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=x-y$. We arrive at the standard integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}\,dz$.

The most common "trick" to evaluate this integral is to consider the product
$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{s^2}{2}}\,ds\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}\,dt\right).$$
This is 
$$\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-\frac{s^2+t^2}{2}}\,ds\,dt.$$
Change to polar coordinates. We have $s^2+t^2=r^2$, and $ds\,dt=r\,dr\,d\theta$, and the integration is easy.

**Remark:** If you are familiar with the *standard normal* distribution from probability theory, you will recall that it has density function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$. The integral of this over the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$ must be $1$. Thus our integral must be $\sqrt{2\pi}$. This is not a *proof* that our integral is $\sqrt{2\pi}$, for it involves believing that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$ truly is a density function. But definite integrals related to this come up often, so the it is useful to remember about the standard normal.

Comment: sorry, im still stuck... i know the integral of $e^x$ is $e^x$ but im not sure how to handle the $z^2$

Comment: @user133466: This is a famous (and important) **definite** integral. You will not be able to find an elementary function which is indefinite integral of $e^{-z^2/2}$, but it turns out that the *definite integral* can be evaluated. If you know probability, you can relate this integral to the *Normal* distribution. You may know the density function for the standard normal. It is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}$. So the integral of that from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ is $1$, and therefore our integral is $\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: There are more details on the definite integral in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2/9292#9292)