# Integrating $\int^{\infty}_0 e^{-x^2}\,dx$ using Feynman's parametrization trick

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

I stumbled upon [this short article](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20130426092828/https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf) on last weekend, it introduces an integral trick that exploits [differentiation under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). On its last page, the author, Mr. Anonymous, left several exercises without any hints, one of them is to evaluate the Gaussian integral
$$
\int^\infty_0 e^{-x^2} \,dx= \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}
$$
using this parametrization trick. I had been evaluating it through trial and error using different paramatrizations, but no luck so far.

---

Here are what I have tried so far:

- A first instinct would be do something like:$$
  I(b) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-f(b)x^2}\,dx
  $$
  for some permissible function $f(\cdot)$, differentiating it will lead to a simple solvable ode:
  $$
  \frac{I'(b)}{I(b)} = -\frac{f'(b)}{2f(b)}
  $$
  which gives:
  $$
  I(b) = \frac{C}{\sqrt{f(b)}}.
  $$
  However, finding this constant $C$ basically is equivalent to evaluating the original integral, we are stuck here without leaving this parametrization trick framework.
- A second try involves an exercise on the same page:
  $$
  I(b) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-\frac{b^2}{x^2}-x^2}dx.
  $$
  Taking derivative and rescaling the integral using change of variable we have:
  $$
  I'(b) = -2I(b).
  $$
  This gives us another impossible to solve constant $C$ in:
  $$
  I(b) = C e^{-2b}
  $$
  without leaving this framework yet again.
- The third try is trying modify Américo Tavares's answer in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2):
  $$
  I(b) = \int^\infty_0 be^{-b^2x^2}\,dx.
  $$
  It is easy to show that:
  $$
  I'(b) = \int^\infty_0 e^{-b^2x^2}\,dx - \int^\infty_0 2b^2 x^2 e^{-b^2x^2}\,dx = 0
  $$
  by an integration by parts identity:
  $$
  \int^\infty_0 x^2 e^{- c x^2}\,dx = \frac{1}{2c}\int^\infty_0 e^{- c x^2}\,dx .
  $$
  Then $I(b) = C$, ouch, stuck again at this constant.

---

Notice in that [Proving $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2) question, Bryan Yocks's answer is somewhat similar to the idea of parametrization, however he has to introduce another parametric integration to produce a definite integral leading to $\arctan$.

Is there such a one shot parametrization trick solution like the author Anonymous claimed to be "creative parameterizations and a dose of differentiation under the integral"?

Comment: I am 90% sure Bryan Yock's solution is the intended one. It appeared in another article on differentiation under the integral sign I read where the Gaussian integral was computed. You give a good analysis of why a simple 1-shot parameterization will not work.

Comment: I was wondering that as well when reading the article. http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf go to the third proof. it's called differentiation under the integral but it's not using the method that other article introduces. so there might be another way still.

Comment: @Potato any link?

Comment: @pad Thanks for the input! Possibly the author is lurking on MSE and read those answers, haha.

Comment: Honest to God I didn't read Bryan Yock's solution before I found mine! I just looked at it, saw two functions and ran away to work with the single function I'd defined P: Hope my answer is a little more satisfying.

Comment: @Sharkos Yes! Definitely.

Comment: @Sharkos I love your website btw, is there an RSS feed such that I could subscribe to the updates?

Comment: Nope! Maybe there should be... To be honest I update things by adding half an article at a time and never finish them so it would kinda suck.

Comment: Another nice application of Feynman's integration trick: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/900398

Comment: I also found this document about differentiation under the integral sign that uses the parameterization trick to solve the Gaussian integral: [https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf). If you ask me, the parameterization used in this document wasn't that obvious, but maybe you can spot that it looks like a promising parameterization with some experience.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just basically independently reinvented Bryan Yock's solution as a more 'pure' version of Feynman.

Let $$I(b) = \int_0^\infty \frac {e^{-x^2}}{1+(x/b)^2} \mathrm d x = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-b^2y^2}}{1+y^2} b\,\mathrm dy$$ so that $I(0)=0$, $I'(0)= \pi/2$ and $I(\infty)$ is the thing we want to evaluate.

Now note that rather than differentiating directly, it's convenient to multiply by some stuff first to save ourselves some trouble. Specifically, note

$$\left(\frac 1 b e^{-b^2}I\right)' = -2b \int_0^\infty e^{-b^2(1+y^2)} \mathrm d y = -2 e^{-b^2} I(\infty)$$

Then usually at this point we would solve the differential equation for all $b$, and use the known information at the origin to infer the information at infinity. Not so easy here because the indefinite integral of $e^{-x^2}$ isn't known. But we don't actually need the solution in between; we only need to relate information at the origin and infinity. Therefore, we can connect these points by simply integrating the equation definitely; applying $\int_0^\infty \mathrm d b$ we obtain

$$-I'(0)= -2 I(\infty)^2 \quad \implies \quad I(\infty) = \frac{\sqrt \pi} 2$$

Comment: I love this answer! Of course, +1.

Comment: +1 for this clear and concise answer.  And apology for the unnecessary edit.  -Mark

Comment: Wait why do we know that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial b}\frac{I(b)}{be^{b^2}}=-2e^{-b^2}I(\infty)$$?

Comment: @clathratus Use the second form of $I(b)$. Firstly simplify $I \exp(-b^2)/b$. Then it should be clear why the derivative is simple to compute.