# Estimating a series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k^2t}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can we prove such an estimate $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty e^{-k^2t}\leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}?$$ I need it in my research....

Comment: Actually the sum equals $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{t}}.$

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that for a monotonically decreasing function, we have that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} f(k) \leq \int_0^{\infty} f(x) dx$$
Move your mouse over the gray area for the solution.

> In your case, $f(k) = e^{-k^2t}$. Hence, we have$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-k^2t} \leq \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2t} dx = \dfrac12 \sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}t}$$ from the following link: [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/)