# $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \exp \{-\frac{1}{2} y^2\} \; dy$

Tags: integration

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \exp \{-\frac{1}{2} y^2\} \; dy$$

I tried letting $u = -\frac{1}{2} y^2$ then $dy = - \frac{1}{\color{red}y} du$... but theres still a $y$ term in $dy$?

Comment: This has definitely been proven on the site already.

Comment: See the explanations here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-e-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2/391194#391194

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If $I$ is the desired integral, then

$$I^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2/2} dx \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-y^2/2} dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(x^2 + y^2)} dy dx$$

Now convert to polar coordinates.