# Integral $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ \frac{-u^2}{2}} du$

Tags: integration

Could you explain what rules are used to compute this integral?
$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{ \frac{-u^2}{2}} du = \sqrt{2\pi}$

Comment: Pretty sure if you look around the website and internet you can easily find them. Hints are : square it and then use polar coordinates.

Comment: See [Gaussian integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral). The article contains several proofs.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Bbb R^2}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}}dydx&=\int_0^\infty\!\!\!\int_0^{2\pi}\rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}2}d\theta d\rho=\\
&=2\pi\int_0^\infty \rho e^{-\frac{\rho^2}2}d\rho=2\pi
\end{align}$$

If we let $I=\int_{\Bbb R}e^{-\frac {x^2}2}dx$, Fubini's theorem and the former computation tell us that $I^2=2\pi$, so $I=\sqrt{2\pi}$.