# How is this step justified into calculating Gaussian integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can anyone give me the justification for the following step in the Gaussian integral evaluation.

$$I^2= \int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx \int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy=\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy$$
Is there some sort of proof I can look at to see why it should be the case that you can combine the two integrals into a double integral.

Comment: Fubini-Tonelli theorem

Comment: Note that there are numerous answers to the question ["Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$"](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9286/139123), although not necessarily one that explains this particular step of the proof in the detail you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is enough that these integrals are independent of each other (one is in $x$, the other in $y$). You can see $\int e^{-x^2} dx$  as a constant with respect to integrating in $y$.

Comment: Okay thanks. The other comment was helpful also. They are both similar responses.