# Stuck in Integretion while deriving Maxwell's Distribution

Tags: definite-integrals

I've got this expression $$\int_0^{\infty}
4 \pi v^2 C e^{-\frac{mv^{2}}{2kT}} \, dv$$ from 0 to ∞.

I've tried everything from by parts to tabular but couldn't get anywhere. Is this even integrable?

Comment: Could you edit the formula ? Thanks

Comment: Trying to. Using a cell phone -_-

Comment: You should also say what is the variable over which we are integrating.

Comment: Why wouldn't parts work?  $$v e^{-a v^2}dv = -\frac1{2 a} d\left (e^{-a v^2}\right )$$

Comment: Am I supposed to do it like this? - $ \int_0^{\infty} bv (v e^{-av^{2}}) \, dv $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change variables so you're carrying less symbols around: set $x=v\sqrt{m/(2kT)}$, so the integral becomes
$$ 4\pi \left(\frac{2kT}{m}\right)^{3/2} \int_0^{\infty} x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx. $$
Now, the last can be done by parts:
$$ \int_0^{\infty} 2x^2 e^{-x^2} \, dx = \left[ -xe^{-x^2} \right]_0^{\infty} + \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2} \, dx; $$
the first term vanishes and the second is [well-known to be](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2) $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$, so the answer is
$$ \int_0^{\infty} 4\pi v^2 e^{-mv^2/(2kT)} \, dv = \pi^{3/2}\left(\frac{2kT}{m}\right)^{3/2}. $$

(Remark: tabular integration is entirely equivalent to integration by parts, so provides nothing except neatness.)

Comment: Thanks Bro. That's a life saver. I didn't know that "well known" formula :) ... That's some awesome math right there! 

(To your remark: I should've written substitution to tabular, my bad.)

Comment: Edit: here's an extra 2 on the last line. It should be $$ \pi^{3/2}\left(\frac{2kT}{m}\right)^{3/2}. $$

Comment: @Raufoon Oh yes, of course...