# Characteristic function of $X^2$ where $X: \mathcal N(0,1)$. $\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} e^{itx^2}\frac{1}{2 \pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$dx?

Tags: probability, integration, definite-integrals, random-variables, normal-distribution

Characteristic function of $X^2$ where $X: \mathcal N(0,1)$. $$\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} e^{itx^2}\frac{1}{2 \pi}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx?$$

I just need to solve this integral. But, I don't know how. When finding the characteristic of $X$ i would write $e^{itX}=\cos tX+ \sin tX$ and then use the fact that $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ is even and $\sin tX$ is odd, over a symetric domain in the integral, making that $0$. But in this case I do not have that. Help on this integral
?

Comment: Use contour integration on $\mathbb{C}$... (your contour will be some special rectangle)

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do, what you say. :)

Comment: Note that $X^2$ is chi-square distributed and that char. functions of chi-square distributed random variables are well known. See for instance this solution http://www.planetmathematics.com/CentralChiDistr.pdf.

Answer (score 1):

When $z$ is a positive real number we have

$$f(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-zt^2}{\rm d}t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{z}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u^2}{\rm d}u = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}$$

where we have used a substitution $u=\sqrt{z}t$ and the result for the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral) whose derivation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2?lq=1).

The integral in the question corresponds to $\frac{1}{2\pi} f\left(\frac{1}{2}-it\right)$ so to solve your problem we need to know $f(z)$ for complex $z$. The short answer is that the formula above holds for complex $z$ as long as Re$(z)>0$ (see proof below), so your integral evaluates to 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi(1-2it)}} = \frac{\cos (\theta )-2 t \sin (\theta )+i (\sin (\theta )+2 t \cos (\theta ))}{\sqrt{2\pi } \left(4 t^2+1\right)^{\frac{3}{4}}}$$
where $\theta = \frac{\arctan(-2t)}{2}$.

---

Let $\gamma$ be a rectangle in the right half plane. We have $|e^{-zt^2}| = e^{-t^2\text{Re}(z)}$ so $\int |e^{-zt^2}|{\rm d}t < \infty$ for all $z$ with Re$(z) > 0$ so by [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem) $$\oint_\gamma f(z){\rm d}z = \oint_\gamma \left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-zt^2}{\rm d}t\right]{\rm d}z = \int_{-\infty}^\infty\left[\oint_\gamma e^{-zt^2}{\rm d}z\right]{\rm d}t = 0$$ Since $\gamma$ was arbitrary [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera's_theorem) tell us that $f(z)$ is analytic in the right half plane and since $f(z) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}$ for $z\in\mathbb{R}_+$ and both $f(z)$ and $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}$ is analytic in the right half plane the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) gives us

$$f(z) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{z}}~~~\text{for all}~~~z\in\mathbb{C}~~~\text{with}~~~\text{Re}(z) > 0$$