# Related integral problem to the Gaussian integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

So according to [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2),
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
I want to solve for this.
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\ln(x)dx$$
My first thought was integration by parts. Since we know what $\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx$ is. But I am open to any other methods you all can give me.

Answer (score 1):

First, consider the following integral:
$$I(\alpha)=  \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha}e^{-x^2}\,dx $$
Next, set $x^2 \rightarrow x$:
$$I(\alpha)= \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}e^{-x}\,dx = \frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right) $$
In this case, we need $\alpha=0$:
$$\frac{\partial I(\alpha)}{\partial \alpha} =\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{\alpha}\ln{(x)}e^{-x^2}\,dx\implies I’(\alpha)= \frac{1}{4}\Gamma'\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{4}\Gamma\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right)\psi\left(\frac{\alpha+1}{2}\right) $$
Note that $\psi$ is the Digamma Function and $\Gamma\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi}$:
$$ I'(0) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4}\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) $$

To simplify this further, note that $\psi(1/2)=-\gamma-\log(4)$.
$$\therefore \int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}\log(x)\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\left(-\gamma -\log(4)\right)}{4}$$

Comment: .... and $\psi(1/2)=-\gamma -\log(4)$.  ;-)) ... +1 for the nice solution.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, correct