# Compute integral: $\int_0^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{-x}\frac{1}{2\pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2} (x^2+y^2)}dx dy $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I would like to resolve this exercise: 
Let $W$ be a Brownian motion with $T_1=1 \text{ year}$ and $T_2=2 \text{ years}$.

I want to compute the probability that $W_{T_1}$ be positive and $W_{T_2}$ negative.

What I did:

$X=W_{T_1}$ and $ Y=W_{T_2}-W_{T_1} $ independent $\sim$ Gaussian 
So our probability is: 
$$P(X>0,X+Y<0)=\int_0^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{-x} \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-  \frac{1}{2} (x^2+y^2)} \, dx \, dy $$

But I don't know how to continue.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. Observe that if you set
$$
f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{-x} e^{-  \frac{1}{2}y^{2}} dy\quad \text{then} \quad f'(x)=- e^{-  \frac{1}{2}x^{2}}
$$ and the initial integral takes the form
$$
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{-x} \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-  \frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})} dx dy&=-\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}f'(x)\cdot f(x)\:dx\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{4 \pi}\left[f^2(x)\right]_{0}^{+\infty}\\\\
&=\frac{f^2(0)}{4\pi} \qquad \left(\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0\right).
\end{align}
$$ 
One has
$$
f(0):=\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-  \frac{1}{2}y^{2}} dy=\int_0^{\infty} e^{-  \frac{1}{2}y^{2}} dy=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}
$$ where we have used the standard [gaussian integral result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2).

Then

> $$
> \int_{0}^{+\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{-x} \frac{1}{2 \pi} e^{-  \frac{1}{2}(x^{2}+y^{2})} dx dy=\frac18.
> $$

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use the integration by parts but I block.

Comment: how about changing variables to polar ! ?

Comment: @KenedYassine I've edited my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The distribution of $(X,Y)$ is rotationally invariant, so the 
chance that it lies in the region $\{(x,y): x>0, x+y<0\}$ (shaded area below) is $1/8$.

[image]