# The integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-t^2}dt$

Tags: definite-integrals, exponential-function, error-function

Me and my highschool teacher have argued about the limit for quite a long time.

We have easily reached the conclusion that integral from $0$ to $x$ of $e^{-t^2}dt$ has a limit somewhere between $0$ and $\pi/2$, as we used a little trick, precisely the inequality $e^t>t+1$ for every real $x$. Replacing $t$ with $t^2$, inversing, and integrating from $0$ to $x$, gives a beautiful $\tan^{-1}$ and $\pi/2$ comes naturally.

Next, the limit seemed impossible to find. One week later, after some google searches, i have found what the limit is. This usually spoils the thrill of a problem, but in this case it only added to the curiosity. My teacher then explained that modern approaches, like a computerised approximation, might have been applied to find the limit, since the erf is not elementary. I have argued that the result was to beautiful to be only the result of computer brute force.

After a really vague introduction to fourier series that he provided, i understood that fourier kind of generalised the first inequality, the one i have used to get the bounds for the integral, with more terms of higher powers.

To be on point: I wish to find a simple proof of the result that the limit is indeed $\sqrt\pi/2$, using the same concepts I am familiar with. I do not know what really Fourier does, but i am open to any new information.

Thank you for your time, i appreciate it a lot. I am also sorry for not using proper mathematical symbols, since I am using the app.

Comment: Can you do *double integrals*?

Comment: your question has an issue of the variable $x$ there.

Comment: You mean the classic integration of a product between a derivate and another function? I might not know the term since english is not my first language

Comment: No. Double integrals, @user4773863

Comment: No, if it's the answer i just got, i do not know of double integration

Comment: Where did you see that the answer is $\sqrt{\pi}/4$?  It should be $\sqrt{\pi}/2.$

Comment: I'll also mention in passing that there are many ways of computing integrals besides just using an explicit antiderivate. Computing the integrals of some quickly-decaying functions over the real line, for example, is a canonical problem in introductory complex analysis classes, and can be done with Cauchy's theorem and some sufficiently clever estimates.

Comment: Complex analysis is something i only heard about. You mean Cauchy's theorem as that generalisation of Lagrange's?

Comment: I am sorry, maybe this problem is really ahead of my knowledge.

Comment: Going back close to the beginning of this site: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2  Many of the approaches there do not use multiple integration.

Comment: Should emphasize that the antiderivative (without explicit endpoints) is the error function and is not elementary. I must wonder whether that is the source of the argument you suggest between you and your teacher. The integral with the ***explicit endpoints*** $0, \infty$ is well known, as you see in the answers.

Comment: No, I mean Cauchy's theorem as in residue calculus.

Comment: How do you prove that the antiderivative of this is actually not elementary? I know there are other methods of computing definite, riemann integrals, but only the fact that the primitive/antiderivative was not know made us think that this was a special problem

Comment: user, I put an answer about that part.

Comment: Thank you, you guys are great!

Comment: You really don't need to write (or edit in) the integrand here as $e^{-t^2}\, dt$ rather than just $e^{-t^2}$; it's completely clear that integration is with respect to $t$. (What else would it be? The number $e$? The mysterious, unused variable $\tau$?)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's useless outside of this one specific integral (and its obvious variants), but here's a trick due to Poisson:
\begin{align*}
\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\; e^{-x^2}\right)^2
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \;dx\;dy\; e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2} \\
  &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty  \;dx\;dy\; e^{-(x^2 + y^2)} \\
  &= \int_0^{2\pi} \!\!\int_0^\infty \;r\,dr\;d\theta\; e^{-r^2} \\
  &= \pi e^{-r^2}\Big\vert_{r=0}^\infty \\
  &= \pi,
\end{align*}
switching to polar coordinates halfway through. Thus the given integral is $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\pi}$.

Comment: Ah, good to know that this trick is due to Poisson, didn't know that. Great answer.

Comment: Lovely trick. Thanks.

Comment: Oddly enough, the modern approach of choosing an appropriate contour and using residue calculus appears to only have been worked out (or at least publicized) by Polya in the late 1940s. Integrating $f(z) = e^{\pi i z^2} / \sin \pi z$ over the parallelogram with vertices $\pm \frac{1}{2} \pm R e^{\pi i/4}$ as $R \to \infty$ gives the result.

Answer (score 3):

Put

$$I:=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx =\int_0^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\implies I^2=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}dy=$$

$$=\frac14\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dxdy=\frac14\int_0^\infty\int_0^{2\pi}re^{-r^2}d\theta\,dr=$$

$$=\frac14\left.2\pi\left(-\frac12\right)e^{-r^2}\right|_0^\infty=\frac\pi4\implies I=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

Comment: to cover the quadrant $[0,\infty)\times[0,\infty)$ only is necessary to take  the angle $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$

Comment: @janmarqz Thank you, edited.

Answer (score 3):

I have two ways to derive it.  The simpler one requires multi-variate calculus.  The more complicated approach uses "differentiation under the integral sign."

Since you don't know multivariate calc, I will do the second.

$F(t) = \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{e^{-t^2(1+x^2)}}{(1+x^2)} dx\\
\frac {dF}{dt} = \int_0^{\infty} -2t e^{-t^2(1+x^2)} dx\\
e^{-t^2}\int_0^{\infty} -2te^{-(tx)^2} dx\\
u = tx, du = t dx\\
e^{-t^2}\int_0^{\infty} -2e^{-u^2} du\\$

$\frac {dF}{dt} = -2e^{-t^2} I$

With $I$ being the our goal.

$\int_0^t \frac {dF}{ds} ds=-2I \int_0^t e^{-s^2} ds\\
F(t) - F(0) = -2I \int_0^t e^{-s^2} ds $

As $t$ goes to infinity:
$F(\infty) - F(0) = -2I^2$

$F(0) =$$ \int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1}{(1+x^2)} dx\\
 \tan^{-1}(\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2}$

$F(\infty) =0$

$-2I^2 = -\frac{\pi}{2}\\
I = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$

Comment: Yes, I missed cleaning up some stuff.  I think I have it all correct right now.

Answer (score 1):

Seems appropriate to address this: any proof that the error function is not elementary is really, really, really difficult. It is the main example in *An Introduction to Differential Algebra* by Irving Kaplansky.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function

Answer (score 0):

We assume that $X\sim\,N(0,1)$ 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f_X(x)dx=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=1$$
as a result
$$2\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\implies\,2\sqrt{2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}du=\sqrt{2\pi}$$
therefore
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}du=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$