# Why did the integral eat the pi?

Tags: integration, exponential-function, radicals, pi

I was reading [this article](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/152.mf1i.spring02/ExpIntegrals.htm) which derives the value for integral of a negative exponent.

I follow the derivation, from circular symmetry, to integration by substitution, and this is the resulting equation:
$$(l(a))^2=\pi\int_0^\infty e^{(-ax)} \, dx=\frac \pi a\tag1$$
(where $l(a)$ is some function on $a$.)

And we take the $\sqrt{}$ of equation (1), which produces:
$$l(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{(-ax^2)} \, dx=\sqrt{\frac \pi a} \text{ for } \operatorname{Re}(a)>0\tag2$$

I understand that the bound became negative infinity because taking the square root gives negative solutions.

However, I don't understand why the exponential factor became $x^2$, and I have no idea where the $\pi$ from equation (1) went. Why did the integral eat the $\pi$?

Comment: That's not how it works.  It becomes $\sqrt{\int_0^\infty e^{-ax}dx}$

Comment: Are you familiar with polar coordinates?  That's where the $\pi$ went.

Comment: Notice they didn't take the square root of $(1)$.  Instead, they squared $(2)$ and turned it into $(1)$.

Comment: "Taking a square root" does not "give negative solutions".  Even the thing that you mean by that phrase has nothing to do with the lower bound of the integral becoming $-\infty$.

Comment: It's really a shame that the equations in the linked article were put in such low-resolution images. It becomes almost impossible to tell what some of the individual letters in each equation are supposed to be. For example, what you read as lower-case L (ell) was meant to be an upper-case I (eye).

Comment: When I saw the title, I honestly thought there was going to be a joke in the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much guys! My integral variable for equation (1) is wrong, it should be $u$ (where $u=r^2=x^2+y^2$), instead of $x$ (thinking it was $x$ had me conflating (1) with the earlier integral of $\int_0^\infty{e^{-ax}}dx$, when both integrals are entirely different). I totally blame this on the font haha. Also, the bounds changed from $-\infty\ to\ 0$ because we switched to integration in terms of $radius\ >\ 0$ (not because of square root). Thank you all once again for the clarification.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think you're conflating two different things in that article.

First, they discuss the integral $\int_0^\infty e^{-a x}\,dx$ and show that it equals $1/a$. This follows by recognizing $\frac{1}{a}e^{-a x}$ as an  antiderivative.

Second, they then want to *separately* compute the integral $I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a x^2}\,dx$. To proceed on this second integral, they write $$I(a)^2 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a x^2}\,dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a y^2}\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a (x^2+y^2)}\,dxdy.$$ To proceed further, they note that the rotational symmetry permits the integration over all $x,y$ to be converted into an integral over $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ with weight $2\pi r\,dr$. Hence $$~~I(a)^2 = \int_0^\infty 2\pi r e^{-a r^2}\,dr=2\pi\underbrace{\int_0^\infty\frac12e^{-au}du}_{\large u=r^2,\ du=2rdr}=2\pi\left[\frac1{2a} e^{-ar^2}\right]_0^\infty = \frac{\pi}{a}~~$$ which upon taking the square root gives the desired result.