# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-(x^2+y^2)} dx dy$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, gaussian-integral

This is the integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} xe^{-(x^2+y^2)} dx dy$$
So i have this:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}\left( \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-x^2}dx\right)dy= \int_{0}^{\infty} -\frac{e^{-y^2}}{2} \left(\lim_{b \to \infty} e^{-b}-e^0\right)$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy$$

How can i resolve that last integral. And i know that the answer is $\frac{\sqrt \pi}{4}$

Comment: Here you have many ways to conclude:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: This question has been solved by the comment of @OlivierOloa. Is there a way to mark it as answered?

Comment: Should be marked as duplicate then.