# Integration with a condition of constant values.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I know that

$$\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}=0$$

Can I say that integration
$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{e^{-ax}}dx=-a$$
  where $a\in [0,-\infty)$. The reason is because the values of a is negative.

Is this true or I am wrong in this assumption.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty}e^{ax}\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_0^n e^{ax}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{a}\lim_{n\to \infty}[e^{ax}+C]_0^n=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{e^{na}-1}{a}
\end{align}
which is $\infty$ is $a\ge 0$, and $-1/a$ if $a<0$.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm wrong but I have to get disposal of integration.The $a$ values remain where itis negative.

Comment: The integral has been solved for all $a$ reals. Hence, it includes the case $a$ negative.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{1}{e^{-ax}}dx=\int_{0}^\infty e^{ax}dx$$

Which converges only for negative values of $a$. When it does converge, you have
$$\int_{0}^\infty e^{ax}dx$$
and, since $a$ is negative, by using $u$-sub, we have
$$=\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{-\infty} e^{u}du$$
$$=-\frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: Can you give me a clarification about  $u$ -sub

Comment: @Emadkareem Changing the variable of integration.