# Prove that Normal distribution integrates to 1 without use of double integrals?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, normal-distribution

Is there a proof that does not involve double integrals for proving normal pdf integrates to 1?

Thanks

Comment: See some of the proofs in this website. http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving $\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} dx = \dfrac{\sqrt \pi}{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-dfrac-sqrt-pi2)

Comment: That question has plenty of methods, several of which don't use double integrals (the Wallis product one, for example).