# Relating product of univariate gaussian integrals to surface area of unit sphere

Tags: polar-coordinates, gaussian-integral, pattern-recognition

In Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop exercise 1.18, the author states the following relation:

$\prod_{i=1} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x_{i}^2} dx_{i}= S_{D} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r^{D-1}dr$

where $S_{D}$ is the surface area of the unit sphere in D dimensions. How is this expression derived?

I know how to show that the integral on the left evaluates to $\pi$ for $n=2$ and therefore for $n=1$ it equals $\sqrt{\pi}$. Multiplying $\sqrt{\pi}$, $D$ times gives  $\pi^{D/2}$.

On the right side of the expression in 2 dimensions I understand that we would have the double integral:

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta$

However, I am unsure why one could rewrite this as:

$S_{D}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdr$

Does this only apply because we are dealing with radius = 1?

Additionally I am unsure how to generalize the expression to any number of dimensions:

$S_{D} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-r^2} r^{D-1}dr$

Comment: This question has been answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2777477/280789