# Is the value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ a **precise** or **approximate** value of the PDF of the standard normal distribution at point $x = 0$?

Tags: terminology

"Doing Math with Python: Use Programming to Explore Algebra, Statistics, Calculus, and More!" in chapter 7 says

> A probability density function, P(x), expresses the probability of the value
>   of a random variable being close to x, an arbitrary value.

Is it true? the pdf is just **close** to?

Is it reasonable to view this close as some kind of approximation? Is probability density function is precise or approximation?

I didn't see any indication of close in [wikipedia on probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

Consider the PDF of the standard normal distribution, $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ at point $x = 0$, is equal to $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.

Is the value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ a **precise** or **approximate** value of the PDF of the standard normal distribution at point $x = 0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability density function specified just that:  the probability a given value arises in a random process governed by the probability density function.  Nevertheless, the probability of any *specific* value $x$ arising (where that value is specified to arbitrary precision) is infinitesimal.  Thus, in practice one has a measuring device with a finite resolution, or specifies a value selected to *finite* precision, and the smaller that range, the closer the measurements are to revealing the density *at* $x$.

So the ideal function describes infinitesimally small ranges (and thus infinitesimally improbable events), but in any experiment there is a *finite* range.

Just look at the pdf of a normal distribution and think about the above explanation.

[image]

Clear?

Comment: Thank you so much. Is the value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ a **precise** or **approximate** value of the PDF of the standard normal distribution at point $x = 0$?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is the *precise* value of the probability density at $x=0$.  But the finite probability is $$\lim_{\Delta \to 0} \int\limits_{x - \Delta}^{x+\Delta} p(x)\ dx$$

Comment: Thanks for your comment! What is does the "finite probability" mean? Is it a canonical term?

Comment: "Finite probability" here colloquially means "non-infinitessimal probability."  Given a normal distribution ${\cal N}(0,1)$, the probability of selecting the *exact* value $x = 1/3$ is infinitesimally small.  The probability you select an $x$ in the range $[1/3 - \Delta, 1/3 + \Delta]$ for $\Delta > 0$ is a *finite* probability.  Clear?

Answer (score 2):

As you say, the pdf of the standard normal is $\varphi(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$.  When we evaluate this at $x=0$ the value is exactly $\frac 1{\sqrt{2\pi}}$.  It comes from integrating $e^{-x^2/2}$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, [getting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2/9292#9292) $\sqrt{2 \pi}$ and using that as a normalizing factor.  There is nothing approximate about it.

The chance of a random variable having the value exactly $0$ or any other number is $0$.  We normally consider the chance the random variable is in some small range around some value.  If we consider the range from $-\epsilon$ to $+\epsilon$, the chance a random variable is within that range is approximately $2\epsilon \cdot \frac 1{\sqrt {2 \pi}}$.  This is approximate because $\varphi(x)$ is not constant over the interval.  It decreases away from $0$.  If $\epsilon$ is small, the decrease is small, and the approximation is good.