# Integral with substitution including variable itself(t=tx)

Tags: integration, substitution

From the [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/11149) about the Gaussian integral,

Bryan Yocks set $~~t=xt$ for $ \int^1 _0 e^{-x^2 t^2} dt$ and got $ \frac{1}{x} \int^x _0 e^{-t^2}dt $

But I can’t figure out why $dt$ changed to $\frac{1}{x} dt$.

How can it be done like this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because we are integrating in respect to $t$, you may regard $x$ as a constant. So, you could say: $y = xt$, and then $dt/dy = 1/x$

Comment: Thank you Jonas, it’s quite clear