# Find $a$ such that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2}dx=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2+y^2}dxdy=\cdots$

Tags: integration, puzzle

This is a puzzle I made up for your amusement.

---

> Which special number, $a$, is such that:
>
> $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2} dx = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2+y^2} dx dy = \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2+y^2+z^2} dx dy dz = \cdots$$

Comment: From where did you get this puzzle? Also have you tried anything?

Comment: @Nyssa I made it up for your ammusement.

Comment: This is an interesting puzzle (and has garnered some interesting answers), but Math.SE isn't really the place for such things. Note that the description of the `puzzle` tag itself says specifically *"If the answer is known to you please do not use this tag to 'riddle' other users, but rather to ask about the correctness of a possible solution or ways to extend and improve an existing solution."* ... Puzzle or not, when you *do* know an answer (especially when you have invented the question), please say so. This helps readers know, for instance, not to waste effort explaining concepts to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the first integral is $I$, the second is $I^2$, the third is $I^3$ and so on.  To have the equality work we can either have $I=0$ or $I=1$.  If $a=0$ we have $I=0$ if we ignore the problem that the integrand is undefined at the origin.  As changing one point does not change the integral, we can just define the integrand to be any value we want at the origin and handwave that away.  Otherwise, we need to find $a$ so that the integral is $1$.  [Alpha](http://%5Cfrac%20%7B%5Csqrt%20%5Cpi%7D%7B2%5Csqrt%7B-%5Clg(a)%7D%7D) tells me that 
$$\int_0^\infty a^{x^2}dx=\frac {\sqrt \pi}{2\sqrt{-\log(a)}} \text{ for } 0 \lt a \lt 1$$  We want the integral to be $\frac 12$, so 
$$\frac {\sqrt \pi}{2\sqrt{-\lg(a)}}=\frac 12\\
\sqrt{-\log (a)}=\sqrt \pi\\
\log(a)=-\pi\\
a=e^{-\pi}\approx 0.0432139$$

Comment: Yes, you are the winner. Well done.

Comment: Same question of the other user: Why $I=I^2=I^3$?

Comment: @Sebastiano:  Because $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2+y^2}dx\ dy = \int_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2}dx \int_{-\infty}^\infty a^{y^2}dy,$ the variables are dummies and the integrals are equal.

Comment: @RossMillikan Ok, Ok :-) thank you very much. It is not important the integration's variable.

Comment: @Sebastiano:  the same trick is used in the evaluation of the Gaussian integral, as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2/9292#9292)

Comment: When $a=0$, the integrand may or may not be defined at the origin depending on your perspective on [what $0^0$ means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

Answer (score 2):

If $L=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2} dx$, then your first equation requires that $L=L^2$. So either $L=0$ or $L=1$.

Since $a^{x^2}\geq0$, the only way for $L$ to be $0$ is if $a=0$.

If $L=1$, then 
$$\begin{align}
&\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2+y^2}\, dx\, dy = 1\\
\implies&\int\limits_{0}^{2\pi}\int\limits_{0}^\infty a^{r^2}\, r\,dr\, d\theta = 1\\
\implies&2\pi\int\limits_{0}^\infty a^{r^2}\, r\,dr = 1\\
\implies&\lim_{t\to\infty}\pi\left[\frac{1}{\ln(a)}a^{r^2}\right]_0^{t} = 1\\
\implies&\lim_{t\to\infty} a^{t^2} = \frac{\ln(a)}{\pi}+1
\end{align}$$

The limit on the left is only defined for $a\leq1$, and it is either $1$ (if $a=1$) or $0$. $a=1$ is not a solution since it makes the original integral infinite. So
$$0=\frac{\ln(a)}{\pi}+1$$ which implies $a=e^{-\pi}$.

Comment: Very nice explanation: why $L=L^2$?

Comment: Good  explanation using polar coordinates.

Comment: It's because $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2+y^2} dx dy=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2}a^{y^2} dx dy=\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{y^2}\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2} dx\right) dy=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2} dx\right)\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{y^2} dy\right)=\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2} dx\right)\left(\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty a^{x^2} dx\right)=L^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, some would probably argue that 0 isn't a number, but 1 also seems to work.

Comment: $1$ does not work because the integrals are infinite.  $0$ has the problem that the integrand is not defined at the origin.  I believe we can accept that, but we need to say something about it.

Comment: But we get $\infty = \infty = \infty = \dots$ for lots of values of $a$.

Comment: I didn't think of those. I guess any number where $a>1$ diverges so all integrals would be infinite! There is another number between 0 and 1 that also works.