# Can I calculate this integral?

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate this integral by DI method but didn't know how to do it (not looking for using gussian formula) :$  \int_{-\infty }^{+\infty} e^{-x^{2}}\,dx $ . Can anyone help me ?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how ? Guass proves it should be sqrt of pi

Comment: @AdibAkkari : I expect your integrand is $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @tommik sorry my bad.

Comment: What is the "DI" method ? "not looking for using gussian formula": what ??

Comment: @fantasie thank you it helped me so much !!!

Comment: @AdibAkkari: Also see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/proving-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx-frac-sqrt-pi2).

Comment: @LightYagami thank you everyone.... Hope didn't annoyed anyone . I AM  A NOOB DON'T LAGH I SEE YOU LAGHING HAHAHAHAHA

Answer (score 1):

The proof is very simple and well known. It is enough to calculate first $I^2$ where $I$ is you integral passing in polar coordinates. Can  you continue with this hint?

The method using polar coordinates is well explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)

If you are familiar with Gaussian distribution you can by-pass the problem with a substitution

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-y^2/2}dy}_{=1}=\sqrt{\pi}$$

This simply substituting

$$x=\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}}$$

and using the known result because inside the integral you have the Gaussian standard density

Comment: Vey simple once you know the trick. Just impossible for a beginner.

Comment: how is that didn't get it ....

Comment: @YvesDaoust : sorry, I will post a sketch now

Comment: Do you expect the OP to know about multiple integrals and Jacobians ?