# Is it possible to calculate this integral?

Tags: integration

I am new to integrals and I am trying to compute this one:

$$
\int \frac{e^-{\frac{\left[ln {T} - \left(\beta-\tau\right)\right]^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \,d\tau
$$

Note that the integrand function is the PDF of the lognormal distribution multiplied by $T$, thus losing the $T$ in the denominator because it cancels out with the multiplying $T$. Furthermore, the mean has been split into two terms, $\beta$ and $\tau$.

Assuming that the values of $\beta$ and $\sigma$ are fixed to be, say, $11.26$ and $1.2$ respectively, and assuming that both $T$ and $\tau$ range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, is this function integrable?

Comment: I don't think there is an antiderivative for that integrand because $e^{-x^2}$ doesn't have an antiderivative.

Comment: Do you really need the _indefinite_ integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is indeed integrable, and you can give a closed form for its antiderivative and its definite integral.

Simplifying the integrand gives
$\require{\cancel}$

$$
\int \frac{e^-{\frac{\left[\ln(T) - \left(\beta-\tau\right)\right]^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \,\mathrm{d}\tau \overset{\color{darkblue}{u =\frac{\ln(T) - \left(\beta-\tau\right)}{\sigma\sqrt{2}} }}{=} \frac{\cancel{\color{darkblue}{\sigma \sqrt{2}}}}{\cancel{\sigma}\sqrt{\cancel{2}\pi}} \int e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
Without limits of integration, the problem reduces to finding an antiderivative for $e^{-x^2}$. This is impossible using elementary functions because the function is transcendental. Because of this, we defined the [error function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html) to be a special function such that
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int e^{-x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{2}\mathrm{erf}
\left(x\right) + C$$
so we can conclude
$$
\int \frac{e^-{\frac{\left[\ln(T) - \left(\beta-\tau\right)\right]^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \,\mathrm{d}\tau =\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{erf}
\left(\frac{\ln(T) - \left(\beta-\tau\right)}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right) + C
$$
Alternatively, since you say $\tau \in (-\infty, \infty)$ you may also want the definite integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^-{\frac{\left[\ln(T) - \left(\beta-\tau\right)\right]^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \,\mathrm{d}\tau \overset{u =\frac{\ln(T) - \left(\beta-\tau\right)}{\sigma\sqrt{2}} }{=} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u =1
$$
where on the last step we used that [$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}\mathrm{d}x = \sqrt{\pi}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/evaluation-of-gaussian-integral-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx), verifying the expected behaviour of a PDF.