# From $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{y\cdot e^{-y^2}}{1+x^2}dydx$ to $\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-x^2}dx\right)^2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Few days ago, I saw [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1395308/686644) by Vivek Kaushik and I began thinking about other possible approach based on it.

We know that:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}y\cdot e^{-y^2}dy = \frac 1 2\qquad\text{and}\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{1+x^2}dx=\frac \pi 2$$
Follows:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{y\cdot e^{-y^2}}{1+x^2}dydx=\frac \pi 4$$
Clearly, this is the square of the Gaussian Integral:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty} e^{-y^2}dy=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$
So, I started wondering if, with some substitution we can get to something of the form:
$$\left(\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}dx\right)^2$$
But, are we able to express that $\frac{y}{1+x^2}$ as the result of another integral involving $e^{-z^2}$? The problem, here, is that I can write:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-z\cdot f(x, y)}dz=\frac{y}{1+x^2}$$
where $f(x, y)=\frac{y}{1+x^2}$, but then we would have:
$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-y^2}\cdot e^{-z\cdot f(x, y)}\,dzdydx$$
which I can't really simplify.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the variable changes $x=\frac t{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$ and $y=\frac {ts}{\sqrt{1+s^2}}$, along with the corresponding  Jacobian $\frac t{1+s^2}$

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy
= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x^2-y^2}dxdy= \int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{te^{-t^2}}{1+s^2}dtds
$$