# convolution of two exponential functions

Tags: calculus, integration, convolution

I'm struggling with the convolution $f \ast g(x)$ where $$f(x)=e^{-x^2}$$ $$g(x)=e^{-5x^2}$$
I integrated $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-t^2}e^{-5(x-t)^2}\ dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-5x^2+10tx-6t^2}\ dt = \left[\frac{1}{10x-12t}e^{-5x^2+10tx-6t^2}\right]_{-b}^a$$
When I expanded using a and b and let them both go to $\infty$ respectively, both parts went to zero. I'm not sure what I did wrong.
$$=\left[\frac{1}{10x-12a}\frac{1}{e^{6a^2-10ax+5x^2}}-\frac{1}{10x+12b}\frac{1}{e^{6b^2+10bx+5x^2}}\right]$$
In every fraction the denominator $\to \infty$ so the whole thing is $0$ but that's incorrect.

Comment: Your antiderivative is not correct (check it by differentiating). You probably want to make a substitution and transform it to a [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral).

Comment: Represente the exponent as $a(t+bx)^2+cx^2$

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/9286/evaluation-of-gaussian-integral-int-0-infty-mathrme-x2-dx

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Thank you! I'll try that instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$-5x^2+10xt-6t^2=-6\left ( t-{5x
\over 6}\right )^2-{5\over 6 }x^2$$ Thus the integral representing the convolution is equal $$e^{-5x^2/6}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-6t^2}\,dt \\ = 6^{-1/2}e^{-5x^2/6}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-t^2}\,dt=\pi^{1/2}6^{-1/2}\,e^{-5x^2/6}$$
On the way we have used the property that the Lebesgue measure is translation invariant.